# Applying a dynamic between statement in SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have two SQL tables. Employees and SalaryBand. I'm using TSQL

Employees:

```
Name|ID|Salary
John|1 |1000
Jack|2 |5000
Mark|3 | 0
```

SalaryBand:

```
PayGrade|SalaryMin|SalaryMax
Low     |0        |999
Med     |1000     |4999
High    |5000     |
```

How do I achieve the following in SQL? I know how I would do it with a CASE WHEN BETWEEN these values e.g. `Case when Salary between 0 and 1000 then 'Low' as Paygrade`.

How do I join the table and "dynamically" apply this transformation such when the values in Salary Band change, so can my calculations.

Output:

```
Name|PayGrade|Salary
John|Med     |1000
Jack|High    |5000
Mark|Low     |0
```

Comment: You can use `BETWEEN` in your `JOIN ON` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` would be most naturally written as:

```
select E.Name, S.PayGrade, E.Salary
from Employees E left join
     SalaryBand S
     on E.Salary >= S.SalaryMin and
        (E.Salary <= S.SalaryMax or S.SalaryMax is null) ;
```

I would suggest that you store the bands with the higher end equal to the next start:

```
PayGrade|SalaryMin|SalaryMax
Low     |0        |1000
Med     |1000     |5000
High    |5000     |
```

And then use:

```
select E.Name, S.PayGrade, E.Salary
from Employees E left join
     SalaryBand S
     on E.Salary >= S.SalaryMin and
        (E.Salary < S.SalaryMax or S.SalaryMax is null) ;
```

This makes the data much less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is at right direction except you need to put 'BETWEEN' clause in WHERE clause instead of SELECT.

Sample sql -

```
select name, salary, Paygrade from employees e join salaryband s
where e.salary between s.salarymin and s.salarymax;
```